# Can I simplify this equation any further?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I have a dot product of to infinite vectors $\Phi(x_1)$ and $\Phi(x_2)$ like this - $(\Phi(x_1),\Phi(x_2))$ = $\Phi(x_1)^T \Phi(x_2)$. And I got to this equation of the dot product:

$(\Phi(x_1),\Phi(x_2)) = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{x_1^m}{\sqrt{m!}} e^{\frac{-x_1^2}{2}} \frac{x_2^m}{\sqrt{m!}} e^{\frac{-x_2^2}{2}}$

Can this term be simplified? I didn't find any common terms to take outside the $\sum$ except of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{m!}}$, anything else I can do?

Comment: $\frac{x_1^m}{\sqrt{m!}}\frac{x_2^m}{\sqrt{m!}} = \frac{(x_1x_2)^m}{m!}$.

Comment: Aren't the exponents the common terms? They don't depend on $m$. The factorial, on the other hand, does. This looks like a Taylor series for $e^x$ evaluated at $(x_1 x_2)$

Comment: @AlexK I put this in my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Factor out the $e^\frac{{-x_1^2}}2$ and $e^\frac{{-x_2^2}}2$. Then, you will have this: $$e^\frac{-(x_1^2+x_2^2)}2\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(x_1)^m}{\sqrt{m!}}\frac{(x_2)^m}{\sqrt{m!}}=e^\frac{-(x_1^2+x_2^2)}2\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(x_1)^m(x_2)^m}{\sqrt{m!}\sqrt{m!}}=e^\frac{-(x_1^2+x_2^2)}2\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(x_1x_2)^m}{m!}=e^\frac{-(x_1^2+x_2^2)}2e^{x_1x_2}=e^{\frac{(x_1-x_2)^2}2}$$

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Comment: Done, though now that it's in that form it could be written as $(x_1-x_2)^2/2$

Comment: @AlexK Both are correct anyway but I didn't see that, very nice!